# log4j2 skip logging additional information

Tags: log4j2

The log4j2 wraps original message in "message" attribute 
I am using JSON layout

```
{
    "timeMillis": 1538154855953,
    "thread": "MyThred #19",
    "level": "INFO",
    "loggerName": "MyLogger",
    "message": "My log message",
    "endOfBatch": false,
    "loggerFqcn": "org.ops4j.pax.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogger",
    "threadId": 63,
    "threadPriority": 5
}
```

I want to avoid the additional fields

Just wanted to have a message like below

```
{
    "message": "My log message"
}
```

Just want to print the data as print statement does
Don't need additional info like loggerName,thread etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "additional info" is the entire purpose of the JSONLayout. If you don't want to use the format that this layout provides then I can think of a few options:

1. Configure a different layout such that it produces JSON output. For example, you could use a `PatternLayout` like this: `<PatternLayout pattern="{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;%m&quot;}%n" />` which produces output like this: `{"message":"log message"}`

The disadvantage with this approach is that it only works well for very simple scenarios. If you wanted to log a more complex data structure than simply a string message it wouldn't work well.

2. Serialize your messages as JSON strings before you pass them to your logger. This wouldn't require any special layout - you could use a simple pattern like `pattern="%m%n"` since your message would already be in JSON format. This would require you to serialize your messages every time before passing them to the logger.
3. Create a custom class that implements the [log4j2 Message interface](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html) and is responsible for generating a JSON string based on the input you provide to its constructor. Then when you log you simply create an instance of your class and pass it the necessary input. With this approach you can incorporate the serialization into the message class itself rather than having to pre-serialize the data, and it's probably less work than creating a [custom layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Layouts).

I hope this points you in the right direction. Without more detailed requirements it's hard to provide an exact solution.